# How to insert UIImage into the database and get the UIImage from database

Tags: ios, sqlite

created table in the database

```
  const char *sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, ADDRESS TEXT, PHONE TEXT, PROFILEPHOTO BLOB)";
```

iam trying to insert the profilephoto data into the database  table.

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sampleimg.png"];
    NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO CONTACTS(name, address, phone, profilephoto) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",name, address, phone,imgData];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
       if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL))
       {

           sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 4, [imageData bytes], [imageData length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
           if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
           {
               NSLog(@"Contact added");
           } else
           {
               status.text = @"Failed to add contact";

           }
           sqlite3_finalize(statement);
       }

      sqlite3_close(contactDB);
   }
```

some times insert query is not executing but  getting some value for the imagedata  profile photo
 Now trying to access the profilephoto

```
 if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM CONTACTS"];
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 4);
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 4) length:length];

                NSLog(@"Length : %d", [imageData length]);
                UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                if(aImage == nil)
                    NSLog(@"No image found.");
                else
                    aImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                imgView.image = aImage;

                NSLog(@"Match found");

                NSLog(@"user: %@ addressContact: %@ phoneNum:%@",user1,addressField,phoneField);


            } else
            {
               NSLog(@"Match not found");
                address = @"";
                phone = @"";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
```

How to insert the image into the database and how to access it properly in iOS

Comment: add another one line NSData to NSString, the nsstring value is passed to the database

Comment: Storing large chunks of binary data in a database is generally a bad idea. A better approach would be saving the file somewhere in the app sandbox, and storing just the path to it in the db.

Comment: convert image in Base64 to store in database

Comment: iam taking the contact profile photo from the addressbook and saved images in the /Library/Cache folder of the app. NSString *imagePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%d.png",filePath,1];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];.Then storing the path into the databse then loading .this process slowing down my app (taking much time to pick the images from the address book).

Answer (score 0):

Your data insertion needs to use an NSString:

```
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSString *imgDataStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[imageData bytes]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following way:

I am assuming that you are aware of data insertion and data fetching with SQLite.

**Insert image in to database:**

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(yourImage, 0.5)];
```

now you can simply insert NSData in to database.

**Getting Image From database**

Get image from the NSData using following code:

```
[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]
```

Comment: int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 4);
                NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 4) length:length];
                
                NSLog(@"Length : %d", [imageData length]);
                UIImage *aImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

Comment: while taking the image aImage is getting nil and  Length : 176361 but image is getting nil

Comment: Try to NSLog("Data ==  %@",imageData);  before converting data in  to image and check if you are getting data or not..

Comment: And also check SQLite database entry by SQLite manager for the MAC.